# Perhaps you would like the overloaded method instead?

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
import java.text.*;

public class template
{
    static void triangle (int height) throws IOException
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i <= height ; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0 ; k < i ; k++)
            {
                System.out.print ("*");
            }
            System.out.println ("");
        }
    }

    public static void main (String str[]) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat ("#");

        double height;
        height = input (height);
        triangle (height);
    }
}
```

Just to start off I would like to say that I am using Ready to Program and just started java in September.

Secondly I would like to ask why it gives me the error `No applicable overload for the method named`triangle`was found in type`template`. All I want to do is call the method triangle so I can output the "*". Also sometimes it asks if I want the overloaded method of triangle. I have no clue what it means please help me, Thank you. I realize that in the grey it shows I have called "input" that is fine I just had to delete it because it was outside of the grey zone and looked confusing.

Comment: You're getting that error because you defined the method to accept an `int` and you're passing it a `double`. They are considered very different data types to Java.

Comment: Thank you Cypher that fixed it, after declaring height, i cant beleive that i looked over something so stupid. RealSkeptic to answer your question it is this:          static double input (double height) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        System.out.print ("Input the height: ");
        height = Integer.parseInt (stdin.readLine ());
        return (height);
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared a variable of type `double`, and you're calling a function that takes a parameter of type `int`. You should change the declaration of `input` so that it also returns an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.text.*;

public class template
{
    static void triangle (double height) throws IOException //here is your error
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i <= height ; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0 ; k < i ; k++)
            {
                System.out.print ("*");
            }
            System.out.println ("");
        }
    }

    public static void main (String str[]) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat ("#");

        double height = 0;
        height = input (height);
        triangle (height);
    }
}
```

Try this and let me know. The triangle method you defined is taking an int as param, and what you called has double. That is causing the trouble. I changed your code. Please check this.

Comment: Thanks Sibidharan! I also didnt declare height. when i fixed the code i did though (i just declared it as 0)!

Comment: @RossParker if my answer helped, mark it as working or upvote. Welcome!